# How to split the sinhala word by specific character of the word in python. I tried with using the length of the word. Is there any other methods?

Tags: python-3.x

I used this. But it is not applicable for all the cases.

```
def splitword(verb_list):
    split = -((-len(verb_list))//2)
    return verb_list[:split], verb_list[split:]
print(verb_list)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: And what specific character do you want to split the sample input by? And what would be the expected output?

Comment: sample inputs are  බලනවා, නටනවා and expected outputs are  බල , නට. So I want to remove 'නවා' from each words

Comment: Is `බලනවා, නටනවා` one string, or a list of two strings?

Comment: Those are list of strings. I used loop to go each string and I want to remove the 'නවා' part in the strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove a specific word from each string in a list you can use the `str.replace()` method in a list comprehension:

```
l = ['බලනවා', 'නටනවා']
l = [s.replace('නවා', '') for s in l]
```

`l` would become:

```
['බල', 'නට']
```